# Handling large datasets with data-driven tests

Tags: robotframework

The problem we have with data-driven tests is that the code becomes unmanageable because of the large amount of different test cases there are.

As an example we have a test template that tests video input and output.

```
Test_Video ${Input_format} ${Output_format} ${Input_channel} ${Output_channel}
```

So we have 8 possible formats and 8 possible in and outputs. That creates 8x8x8x8=4096 possible test cases. Writing that much test cases is way to much work.

My question is how do you handle such large datasets and make the code more manageable. Do we need to change the way we are testing?

I've tried using a :FOR loop but that doesn't show each iteration as a separate test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had this problem, I would write a tiny script that generates the test suite for me.

Comment: I guess if there is no other way I'll accept this answer.